# alloc and release problems

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I can't figure out why my app is crashing after a few times I'm doing:

potionsT is nonatomic, retain, readonly.

```
-(void)First:(NSString*)Potions {

    potionsT = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:Potions];
}

-(void)After:(NSString*)Potions {
    [potionsT release];
    potionsT = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:Potions];
```

You see, I'm first calling First and after that I'm calling a few times After: and wopes, it crashes. with ECX_BAD_ACCESS.. I'm pretty noob with all that memory manage thing, I know that... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of retained property is it handles retain and release when you set it.

```
- (void)first:(NSString*)potions
{
    self.potionsT = potions; // will automatically release old value and retain new
}

- (void)after:(NSString*)potions
{
    self.potionsT = potions; // same as above
}
```

Also note how i renamed your `Potions` to `potions`, `First:` to `first:`, and `After:` to `after:`. Objective-C naming convention is to start variables and methods with lowercase letter, and class names with capital.

Answer (score 2):

Did you `@synthesize` the property in the `@implementation` for the class? If so, then you should use:

```
self.potionsT = Potions;
```

if you use

```
potionsT = ...
```

then you are accessing the ivar, not the property. To access the property and let it do the memory management for you, you must precede it with an instance reference, and that can also be self.

If you use the property, you should not release potionsT manually, since the property already does that for you.

Comment: There can be many reasons your code crashes. We'd have to see more of your code to see why it "crashes" (where, how?). Use a debugger to find out where it happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you've set up potionsT as a property, you should access it that way:

```
-(void)first:(NSString*)potions {
    self.potionsT = potions;
}

-(void)after:(NSString*)potions {
    self.potionsT = potions;
}
```

In both cases, I changed your code to use the accessor for `potionsT` (that's what the `self.potionsT` means). I'm also not creating a new string, but just retaining the provided one. Since NSStrings are immutable, the result is the same. For best results, though, change the `potionT` property from `retain` to `copy`. That way, if a mutable string gets passed in, it'll be copied instead of retained (and immutable strings will still just be retained).

Comment: "it crashes" doesn't go very far toward solving the problem. Look at the resulting stack trace and figure out *what* crashes. What line? If you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, you're dereferencing a bad pointer, so figure out what pointer it was and how it became invalid.